# Looping Excel VBA Macro that Runs other Macros

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

I am trying to make a vba program that will take the stock ticker in column A and paste it on a different "settings" sheet in a cell, then the program will execute two other vba codes that download historical data and backtest my formula. Then the program will return to the "data" sheet and print the value in "B10" on "settings" into column D in "data". I need the printed value to be in column d corresponding to the ticker's row. The program has to repeat 500 times. Can you help me find how to do this or point out what is wrong in my code? Thanks!

```
Sub finalbalance()

Dim ticker As Range
Dim i As Long
Sheets("results").Activate
    Set ticker = ActiveCell
    For i = 1 To 500
        Sheets("results").Activate
        ticker.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Settings").Select
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.Run "datadownload"
        Application.Run "btest"
        ticker.Offset(0, 3) = Sheets("settings").Range("B10")
        ticker.Address = ticker.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't assign a value to the .Address property:

```
'Instead of
ticker.Address = ticker.Offset(1, 0)

'Use:
Set ticker = ticker.offset(1, 0)
```

And that will get your code working as is.  However, the select statements really aren't necessary and should be avoided.  Here's a cleaned up version of the code:

```
Sub finalbalance()

    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim wsSettings As Worksheet
    Dim rngStartCell As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim lNumReps As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsResults = Sheets("Results")
    Set wsSettings = Sheets("Settings")
    Set rngStartCell = wsResults.Range("A2")

    lNumReps = 500
    ReDim arrResults(1 To lNumReps)

    For i = 1 To lNumReps
        wsSettings.Range("B1").Value = rngStartCell.Offset(i - 1).Value
        Application.Run "datadownload"
        Application.Run "btest"
        arrResults(i) = wsSettings.Range("B10").Value
    Next i

    rngStartCell.Offset(, 3).Resize(lNumReps).Value = Application.Transpose(arrResults)

End Sub
```